# How do I restrict access to sys_context in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, security

I would like to be able to prevent a readonly database user from being able to access some system functions, such as sys_context. i.e.

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;
SELECT SYS.DATABASE_NAME FROM dual;
SELECT dbms_utility.port_string FROM dual;
```

*Edit: With the responses provided here and additional things tried on my side, a lengthy report was provided to biz. They decided that attempting to restrict these rights were not worth the risk and thus it was dropped.

Comment: As there are potentially internal features that depend on that access, I'm not sure it is possible. What is the specific problem or issue that you are trying to address?

Comment: Thanks heath roush.  `SYS_CONTEXT` is special builtin with public access, with finer-grain control to specific namespaces.  The other two examples you provided could be locked-down, but the mechanism to do so involves revoking access from `PUBLIC`, which would change default behavior for all users, not just the one target, unless a compensatory role were to be granted to other (and future) users.  This would increase complexity, risk, and maintenance (should not be done lightly).  Thanks

Comment: @pmdba In this application, users are able to submit sql queries to run against the db, so they can generate their own reports. The app makes sure they don't query some special tables, checks the execution plan to make sure they aren't trying something funny, and then runs the query using a special db user where this is its only job. A penetration tester discovered they were able to run the above queries and some others and it was determined that our users should not be allowed to do this.

Comment: @alexgibbs Thanks for your feedback. I believe the issues you note about removing access to PUBLIC in my case are minimal. Could you outline how to revoke access to sys.database_name and dbms_utility? From your comment, are you saying there is not a way to revoke access to sys_context? Does that mean there's an easy way to revoke access to 'USERENV'?

Comment: No, you can't revoke access to USERENV, and in general there's little or no concern with things granted to PUBLIC any more. Even the US DOD doesn't recommend removing PUBLIC privileges in its lockdown guidelines. Is the application a thick client that logs the user directly into the DB, or a web application using a connection pool? What is the concern about users having access to that specific information, given that their access to the DB is controlled through a middle tier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to prevent access to `SYS_CONTEXT`, but you can prevent access to `DATABASE_NAME` and `DBMS_UTILITY`:

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_UTILITY FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE EXECUTE ON SYS.DATABASE_NAME FROM PUBLIC;
```

However, Oracle warns very strongly in Support Document Doc ID 247093.1 to revoke any privileges from PUBLIC. Basically, they will not support your applications if you do so, you're on your own.

What's wrong with finding out the session number (SID)? It changes every time you connect...

Personally, I find it totally silly to consider the database name a security risk. The functions your pentesters complained about are accessible to PUBLIC for decades. Reminds me a bit of the Grimms' Fairy Tale where the hobgoblin dies once the miller's daughter guesses his name "Rumpelstiltskin"...